# How to find the values of $m$ so $A \cap B = \emptyset$ and $A \cup B = (-3,+\infty)$?

Tags: equation-solving

I have two intervals $A = (-3, m^2- 2]$ and $B=[m, +\infty)$. How to find the values of $m$ so that $A \cap B = \emptyset$ and $A \cup B = (-3,+\infty)$? 
I tried

```
{a = x > -3 && x < m^2 - 2, b = x >= m} {Reduce[a || b]}
```

and

```
{a = x > -3 && x < m^2 - 2, b = x >= m}
{Reduce[a && b]}
```

We have $A \cap B = \emptyset$ when and only when $$\begin{cases}
m^2 - 2 > -3&\\
m^2 - 2 <m.
\end{cases}$$  and $A \cup B = (-3,+\infty)$ when and  only when  $$\begin{cases}
m^2 - 2 > -3&\\
m^2 - 2 \geqslant m.
\end{cases}$$ Therefore we need to solve two systems of inequalities.

Comment: Two systems of inequalities to be solved at the same time are just one system consisting of all the inequalities from the two systems.

Comment: Because each of $A$ and $B$ is relatively closed in $A\cup B$ and $A\cup B$ is connected, the only possible solutions would be when either $A$ or $B$ is empty.  (It would be interesting to find ways to get *Mathematica* to perform such forms of topological reasoning.)

Comment: Why do you wrap your commands in `{  }`?

Answer (score 2):

Just reduce the four inequalities you gave:

```
Reduce[m^2 - 2 > -3 && m^2 - 2 < m && m^2 - 2 > -3 && m^2 - 2 >= m, m]

(* False *)
```

Your second and fourth inequalities contradict each other, so there is no solution.